# Salvar informações de arquivo JSON em banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Penso na possibilidade de um sistema Web salvar informações de um cadastro em um arquivo JSON no dispositivo do cliente, e que posteriormente seria envido ao BD. Isto vai acontecer quando o cliente estiver em um ambiente onde não é possível acesso a internet no momento da realização do cadastro para sincronizar com o BD online. Há alguma divergência ou uma melhor prática para esta implementação?

Comment: sistema web... tem q estar na internet né... do contrário tem q ser um sistema mobile que salve em um banco sqlite por exemplo... depois faça a sincronização...

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com o [IndexedDB](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325135/Getting-Started-with-IndexedDB) e fazer a sincronização com o seu BD remoto sempre que necessário.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não necessariamente. Pode-se facilmente persistir dado na área de Storage do browser. É um sistema simples, de chave/valor, mas atende muito bem.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis concordo com sua afirmação. Eu pensei em algo como ASP.NET Core Self Host para ser hospedado no próprio dispositivo, pois creio que o sistema será instalado em tabletes com Android.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi É também uma possibilidade de se fazer isto. Mas preciso o tamanho do Storage do browser para não ultrapassar com a quantidade de informação.

Comment: a solução do @ThiagoLunardi parece ser boa, mas depende do propósito... eu erroneamente pensava se tratar de dados temporários, mas a limitação acontece no tamanho: "Pelo menos 5MB": https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu iria por um aplicativo compilado, em Xamarim por exemplo...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis creio que será o melhor mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Isso não é complicado, especialmente sendo sistema Web.

Todos os meios de ambiente *client* possuem uma área de *Storage* - até mesmo *browsers*. Normalmente essas área de *storage* funcionam de forma simples, com chave e valor - *key value*.

Vc pode implementar algo como o seguinte pseudo código:

```
sendData = (data) => {
  _http.send(data, 
    (response) => { success(response); },
    (error) => { _retryStorage.add(data); });
};
```

Então, ter um serviço periodicamente fazendo algo como:

```
var data = _retryStorage.pop();
data && sendData(data);
```

Então, se não tiver conseguido enviar o dado para o servidor, joga no storage para recoperar depois. Então um outro serviço assincrono fica "ouvindo" essa fila, e se tiver algo lá, tenta re-enviar.

Lembre-se que isso é apenas um pseudo código, há muito a desenvolver para que funcione como esperado, mas é um bom caminho a ser seguido.

Comment: Bacana a ideia. Obrigado pela dica Thiago.